# Extraer filas de una base de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd  
datos=pd.read_csv('datos.csv', header=0 )
datos=(datos[datos.iloc[:,3]>=0]) 
anios1=datos[datos.iloc[:,2]==1975]
```

Utilice este código para leer una base datos, esta base de datos almacena la precipitación en cierta zona cada día todos los días desde 1950 hasta 2015. Posteriormente extraje como una nueva base de datos los valores que corresponden a el año 1975.
La idea del código en general es obtener la precipitación mas alta de cada mes de ese año y hacer un gráfico con esos datos. 
No encontré la manera de extraer las filas con los valores que necesito como una nueva base de datos.[image: Captura de como esta organizada la base de datos]

Comment: Pedro, has hecho una pregunta hace unas horas que sin duda es un duplicado de esta. La respuesta que te he dado no te ha servido?

Comment: Creí que debía plantear de mejor manera mi pregunta, pero si, sin duda me sirvió tu ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

datos=(datos[datos.iloc[:,3]>=0])
anios1=datos[datos.iloc[:,2]==1975]
esto retorna True o False solamente y no los valores

Creo que esto te puede servir
el archivo lluvia.cvs contiene las siguientes filas:
Año,Mes,Dia,Lluvia
1974,12,24,0.0
1974,12,25,0.0
1974,12,26,0.0
1974,12,27,0.0
1974,12,28,0.0
1974,12,29,0.0
1974,12,30,0.0
1974,12,31,0.0
1975,1,1,0.0
1975,1,2,0.0
1975,1,3,0.0
1975,1,4,0.0
1975,1,5,0.4
1975,1,6,0.0
1975,1,7,0.6
1975,1,8,0.0
1975,1,9,0.0
1975,1,10,3.0
1975,1,11,0.0
1975,1,12,4.5
1975,1,13,0.0
1975,1,14,0.0

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3  
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
"""  
Created on Wed Nov 15 11:55:15 2017  
lluvia75.py  
Lluvias en 1975  
@author: jab  
"""  

import pandas as pd  

datos = pd.read_csv('lluvia.csv', header = 0)  
lluvias = pd.DataFrame()  
for index, row in datos.iterrows():  
...    if row[0] == 1975.0 and row[3] > 0.0:  
...    lluvias = lluvias.append(row)  
    
print(lluvias)
```

**Resultado:**

```
    Año      Dia    Lluvia Mes 
12  1975.0   5.0     0.4  1.0  
14  1975.0   7.0     0.6  1.0  
17  1975.0  10.0     3.0  1.0  
19  1975.0  12.0     4.5  1.0
```